# ugettext_lazy/pgettext_lazy not working in Django sub-application

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-i18n

I am translating a Django site with a sub-application.

Let's say the top level site is called 'main_site' and the sub application is called 'sub_app'.

In main_site, I am using only trans and blocktrans tags for translation (with context markers). After farting around for a day or two, I can now mark text with the same strings using the 'context' keyword.

For example,
contact.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans "Name" context "ContactForm" %}">
```

register.html

```
<h5 class="text-center">{% trans "Name" context "RegisterForm" %}</h5>
```

makemessages correctly creates these entries in the top level PO file and I can update them with different translations and Django renders them correctly. I do not use u/pgettext_lazy at all in the top-level application.

With that working, I moved on to the I18N of sub_app.

In forms.py I have:

```
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
     email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}), label=ugettext_lazy('Email'))
```

makemessages again creates the entry correctly in sub_app's PO file.

I use that form in register.html from the top-level application like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">                                                     
        {% bootstrap_field form.email form_group_class="form-group" label_class="control-label" %}
    </div>
</div>
```

So the problem is when this form gets rendered, the translated text is not fetched for the form label.

I don't know if this is because Django can't lazy translate the form fields of a sub-app (seems unlikely) or because I'm using django-bootstrap3 tags to render the form (also seems unlikely due to [this](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/issues/181)) but I'm pretty much stuck.

Eventually, I want to do this:

```
email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}), label=pgettext_lazy(u'UserForm', u'Email'))
```

but uggettext_lazy already seems like a bridge too far.

Comment: Can you try using `pgettext_lazy` in the top-level application? Does it work there?

Comment: No, sir. ugettext_lazy doesn't seem to working from the main application either. Thanks for replying. Any tips?

Comment: Incidentally, pgettext_lazy doesn't work either.

Comment: Where are you running the `makemessages` command? According to docs, it should be run either from your project directory (where you manage.py  file is) or from your apps. Also, did you remember to compile your translations using `compilemessages` command?

Comment: I'm running makemessages from the project folder. I also always run compilemessages after I've added the translations (and even restart the server). When compilemessages runs, it shows that it's picked up all the PO files in the file hierarchy.